# Rails 4 auto_link: (undefined method `unpack' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autolink

I'm using the `rails_autolink` gem and I'm getting this:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `unpack' for nil:NilClass)
```

For this line:

```
<span><%= auto_link(@job.apply) %></span>
```

Comment: Could you paste the whole backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

`@job.apply` may be `nil`. Use a guard or convert to string:

```
<span><%= auto_link(@job.apply.to_s) %></span>

<span><%= auto_link("#{@job.apply}") %></span>

<span><%= auto_link(@job.apply) if @job.apply %></span>
```